# date change script

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/sh

after=$(date - date "today - $(date +% d) days" +%Y-%m-%d)

now=$(date +%Y%m01) 

sed -i 's/20180301/'$now'/g' hyb.txt; 

sed -i 's/2018-02-28/'$after'/g' hyb.txt;
```

How to assign variables to the format of my dates 20180301 and 2018-02-28 to no longer put them as I do in my script.

Comment: Could you describe what's the output you expect? What do you mean by "flatten"?

Comment: You're missing quotes around your `+% Y-% m-% d` segments. Or else you've put spaces here where there is none in your actual code. Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: for the first question I was wrong I meant to pluck or put

Comment: for your second comment the change was made

Comment: It looks like `now` is supposed to be the first day of this month and  `after` is supposed to be the last day of the previous month: is that right?

Comment: this is correct

Comment: You might consider more descriptive variable names: it's confusing that "after" occurs *before* "now".

Comment: Note that the (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/544442/changement-de-date)[original version of this question] used more descriptive/verbose variable names "dateoflastdayofprecedingmonth" and "dateoffirstdayofcurrentmonth".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming my assumption in the comment above is correct:

```
# "now" == first day of this month: format YYYYmmdd
now=$( date "+%Y%m01" )

# "after" == last day of previous month: format YYYY-mm-dd
after=$( date -d "$now - 1 day" "+%Y-%m-%d" )

echo "now=$now"         # now=20190901
echo "after=$after"     # after=2019-08-31
```

Comment: the exact result is that it must give

Comment: I do not want to put 20180301 and 2018-02-28 in the sed. I want to assign variables to their format that will take their place to change the dates each time

Comment: I don't understand. Please edit your question to include the contents of `hyb.txt` -- see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on StackOverflow.

Comment: existing script
after = $ (date - date "today - $ (date +% d) days" +%Y-%m-% d)

now = $ (date +% Y% m01)

sed -i 's / 20180301 /' $ now '/ g' hyb.txt;

sed-i 's / 2018-02-28 /' $ after '/ g' hyb.txt;

change

after = $ (date - date "today - $ (date +% d) days" +% Y-% m-% d)

now = $ (date +% Y% m01)

sed -i 's / variable assigned to the format 20180301 /' $ now '/ g' hyb.txt;

sed -i 's / variable assigned in the format 2018-02-28 /' $ after '/ g' hyb.txt;

Comment: I don't understand "variable assigned in the format 2018-02-28" -- what should the **value** of that variable be? What is your goal? What dates occur in hyb.txt?

Comment: Are you actually asking "what is the regular expression to match a date in the format  YYYY-mm-dd?"

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
#!/bin/sh

file=hyb.txt

nowfile=${1:-20180301}
afterfile="${2:-"$(date -d "$nowfile -1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d")"}"

now=$(date +%Y%m01) 
after=$(date -d "$now -1 days" +%Y-%m-%d)

echo sed -i 's/'"$nowfile"'/'"$now"'/g' "$file"; 
echo sed -i 's/'"$afterfile"'/'"$after"'/g' "$file";
```

The script needs arguments.

Argument 1 is the `now` value inside the file that needs to be changed. If argument 1 is not given it defaults to `20180301`.

Argument 2 is the `after` value to be changed inside the file (`afterfile`). If not given, the value is calculated from the value of the `now` inside the file (`nowfile`).

Call the script as `./script 20180301 2018-02-28` to act as your original script.

Call `./script 20180901` (no second argument) to have the script calculate the new `afterfile` value (results in `20180831`).

If the values calculated work as you need, remove the two `echo` before the sed's to make the script process the file.